# Glossy CSS3 Image Overlay doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I found this code on a tutorial to apply a glossy overlay on a DIV, right?

```
.glossy .image-wrap {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.glossy .image-wrap:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,.1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%);
}
```

Okay, now I want to apply this glossy overlay only on the post images, so the code looks now like this:

```
.post img .image-wrap {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.post img .image-wrap:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,.1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%);
}
```

But It doesn't work!! The CSS style is not working on the post images, please what am I doing wrong? [This is the website](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar) I'm applying the style. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An image cannot have children which you seem to be targeting in your CSS.

You would need to wrap each image in an `inline-block` div (perhaps with a class of `glossy`) and then use the original technique.

I would suggest that you re-examine the source of your code and see if this is not the technique being used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But if I want to add the style to every single post image (automatically), what's the code I need? Again, thanks

Comment: You CAN'T....for this technique to work it requires that the image be the child of an element holding **only** the image. That's why I suggested you review the original source of the code, it should tell you that.

Comment: Ohh okay I'll do that. Thank you! :)